# Google Cloud Messaging - Will it work when app is not running

Tags: android

I have looked on similar threads however couldn't find a definitive answer.

For android 3.1+, if an app is force killed it doesn't receive broadcasts.

Force killed stops all running services and proccesses.

Does this mean if my app doesn't have a running service and is swiped out of recent apps then it will not receive GCM notifications?

Or does this only apply to when the force stop button is actually pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you know the (deprecated) version of GCM. There we had to implement a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` service which was started automatically when reveicing any GCM notification. This service had to "wake up" your app and in turn is able to start any of your own services.

This of course is still valid for the most recent GCM API-version but there you have to extend `GcmListenerService` which also is called by a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`.

For detailed information on how to implement this please refer to [Google's code sample](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-receive).

To say it short - yes it will work if it is implemented correctly.